# Terraform Escape sequence selector

Tags: terraform

I have password with `f\3tix#`

I created variable in below format

```
Variable password{
    Type = string
    Default =“f\3tix#”
}
```

When I run `terraform validate` I am getting error "symbol 3 is not valid escape sequence selector".

Answer (score 1):

The backslash character is the escape character in Terraform, much like in C-like languages. If you want to use the `\` character, you need to escape it with another `\`, so your string becomes

```
Default ="f\\3tix#"
```

Note that if you define an `output` with the above value, Terraform will print the value in its escaped form, which can be confusing, because at the first glance, it *seems* that Terraform uses `f\\3tix#` as the string value, but it is not so. The above value will be used as `f\3tix#` by Terraform.